# Stage 301 redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For a page relaunch I have to redirect some old urls.
Most of them work fine... expl:

```
Redirect 301 /en/agency/profile/ /agency
```

But some of them show a really strage results expl:

```
Redirect 301 /en/brands/name-of-project/ /en/projects/name-of-project/
```

-> leads to:
`/en/projectsname-of-project/`

So it somehow ignore one slash.
Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Here is the rest of the .htaccess (default stuff of Kirby CMS, comes before my redirects)

```
# Kirby .htaccess
# revision 2020-06-15

# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# enable awesome urls. i.e.:
# http://yourdomain.com/about-us/team
RewriteEngine on

# make sure to set the RewriteBase correctly
# if you are running the site in a subfolder;
# otherwise links or the entire site will break.
#
# If your homepage is http://yourdomain.com/mysite,
# set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /mysite

# In some environments it's necessary to
# set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /

# block files and folders beginning with a dot, such as .git
# except for the .well-known folder, which is used for Let's Encrypt and security.txt
RewriteRule (^|/)\.(?!well-known\/) index.php [L]

# block all files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*) index.php [L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) index.php [L]

# block direct access to Kirby and the Panel sources
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# pass the Authorization header to PHP
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

# compress text file responses
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @anubhava tried 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^en/brands/name\-of\-project/$ /en/projects/name-of-project? [R=301,L]

same result

Comment: You probably have an earlier Redirect directive interfering here. Did you take into account that this does _prefix_ based matching?

Comment: ok make sure you keep your new 301  rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line and you test if after completely removing browser cache.